# Resolving the "error in pandas setup command" error?

Tags: python, pandas, windows, powershell

I am installing libraries from a text file via Windows Powershell but I keep encountering this error.
The full error is "setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer. If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
pytz >= 2011k".

I am not sure what this means.I have tried restricting the installation process such that it installs all libraries except the pandas library but more errors arise.

Comment: See : https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/j9eczr/how_to_pip_install_pandas_despite_pep517/?force_isolation=true

Comment: The solution in this link seems to be for Linux, but I am not sure of the equivalent for Windows. Also I tried installing pandas individually which was fine. However, if I remove the pandas library from the requirements.txt file I get multiple errors.

Comment: What version of python are you using?  pandas has doesn't work with python 3.10 according to following : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43969?force_isolation=true

Comment: Using Python 3.11.2

Comment: You need to check if 3.11.2 is compatible with Pandas.

Comment: I suggest you use python 3.9